# Summing adjacent rows based on conditionals

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame similar to this

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
action <- c("for","l","for","f","l","l","for","for","for","f")
time <- c(45,35,24,56,100,121,30,10,35,143)
dframe <- data.frame(id,action,time)
```

Only the action "for" repeats itself in consecutive rows within each unique id. I would like to collapse these rows into one row that sums the time for action "for". I want to do this only within each unique id AND when they follow each other (as in id==3, not id==1)

I tried the following code but this does not distinguish between the actions that follow one after another but rather sums all occurrences of "for" within the unique id.

```
aggregate(action_time ~ id + act, data=mean.event, FUN=sum)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rle()`, `inverse.rle()`, and the **data.table** package:

```
## Reproduce example data, naming it df and setting stringsAsFactors=FALSE    
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
action <- c("for","l","for","f","l","l","for","for","for","f")
time <- c(45,35,24,56,100,121,30,10,35,143)
df <- data.frame(id,action,time, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Use rle() and inverse.rle() to give each run of "for"s a distinct name
r <- rle(df$action)
r$values <- paste0(r$values, seq_along(r$values))
(r <- inverse.rle(r))
#  [1] "for1" "l2"   "for3" "f4"   "l5"   "l5"   "for6" "for6" "for6" "f7"  

## Use data.table to subset by run of "for"s *and* by id, collapsing only
## sub-data.tables consisting of consecutive "for"s within an id.
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[ , if(action[1]=="for") {
          X <- .SD[1,]       
          X$time <- sum(time) 
          X
      } else {.SD}, 
   by=list(r, id)][,-1,with=FALSE]
#    id action time
# 1:  1    for   45
# 2:  1      l   35
# 3:  1    for   24
# 4:  2      f   56
# 5:  2      l  100
# 6:  3      l  121
# 7:  3    for   75
# 8:  3      f  143
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy variable that indicates whether or not your constraints are met.
For example, dummy variable 'x1' will be unique for each group consecutive rows where action=="for":

```
dframe$x1 <- with(dframe, cumsum(c(1,action[1:(length(action)-1)] != action[2:length(action)])))
```

Use this variable in your aggregate function (note subset and some other changes from your code in the question):

```
aggregate(time ~ id + x1, data=dframe[dframe$action=="for",], FUN=sum)

  id x1 time
1  1  1   45
2  1  3   24
3  3  6   75
```

Note that you also need to set stringsAsFactors=F when you create the data frame, as cryo11 pointed out.

Comment: That will also collapse the two `l`'s at rows 5 and 6 of the data.frame.

Comment: As far as I understand, he does not want to have the first two `for`s counted, i.e. "I want to do this only within each unique id **AND when they follow each other** (as in id==3, **not id==1**)".

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went with @Josh O'Brien as I am a fan of data.table and it preserved the ordering of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is the result that you want.
BTW: I am assuming that you have set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

```
res=Reduce("rbind",lapply(split(dframe,id),function(x) {
  tmp=rle(x$action)
  tmp$values=ifelse(tmp$values!="for"|(tmp$values=="for"&tmp$lengths==1),
                    TRUE,
                    FALSE)
  idx=inverse.rle(tmp)
  na.omit(rbind(data.frame(x[idx,setdiff(colnames(x),"time")],
                           time=x[idx,"time"]),
                data.frame(x[!idx,setdiff(colnames(x),"time")][1,],
                           time=sum(x[!idx,"time"]))
                )
          )
  }))
rownames(res)=NULL
res
```

Gives

```
#  id action time
#1  1    for   45
#2  1      l   35
#3  1    for   24
#4  2      f   56
#5  2      l  100
#6  3      l  121
#7  3      f  143
#8  3    for   75
```

Comment: Are you certain this will give the correct answer when a sequence of `"for"`s starts in one id and runs on into the next one? (i.e., consider a data.frame containing several `id` values and in which all rows had a value of `"for"` in their `action` column...)